# question about the ratio test proof part 1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = L < 1$, then the series converges (part 1 of ratio test).

Proof:

Since $L < 1$, $\exists r$ s.t. $0 \leq L < r < 1$. In particular,

$\displaystyle|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| < r \Rightarrow |a_{n+1}| < |a_{n}|r$.

For $n \geq N$, $|a_{N+2}| < |a_{N+1}|r < |a_{N}|r^2$.   ($\ast$)

The pattern will continue to $|a_{N+k}| < |a_{N}|r^k$.

I will just roughly describe the rest of the proof. $|a_{N}|r^k$ is a geometric series, hence converges and by the basic comparison test, $|a_{N+k}|$ will converge (absolutely).

Okay so the algebra in this proof makes sense to me, but there a couple of parts I still do not get. I do not understand why $r$ goes up a power each time at $\ast$. The line above that one, it was just $|a_{n}|r$. Why does it change? I also don't get why we replace $n$ with $N$ in the proof. I know $N$ is an integer but I still don't understand why we do it. I was always iffy on the whole $n > N$ idea. What is happening visually? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $L>1$ and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=L$$

Then by definition, this means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a number $N$ such that whenever $n>N$ we have

$$L-\epsilon<\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|<L+\epsilon \tag 1$$

Note that here $\epsilon>0$ is any number given, whereas $N$, which depends on $\epsilon$, can be found (i.e., $N(\epsilon)$ exists).

Now since $(1)$ is true for all $\epsilon>0$, then it is true for $\epsilon'$ so small that $L+\epsilon' <r<1$ for some $r<1$.

Now, given any $\epsilon>0$ with $\epsilon<\epsilon'$, there exists a number $N(\epsilon)$ such that whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|<r \tag 2$$

---

**On the Questions Regarding $N$ and Increasing Powers of $r$**

In particular, since $(2)$ is valid for all $n>N$, then starting with $n=N+1$, and proceeding with $n=N+2$, $n=N+3$, $\cdots n=N+m$, we certainly can write

$$\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{a_{N+2}}{a_{N+1}}\right|<r\implies |a_{N+2}|<r|a_{N+1}|\\\\
&\left|\frac{a_{N+3}}{a_{N+2}}\right|<r\implies |a_{N+3}|<r|a_{N+2}|<r^2|a_{N+1}|\\\\
&\left|\frac{a_{N+4}}{a_{N+3}}\right|<r\implies |a_{N+4}|<r|a_{N+3}|<r^2|a_{N+2}|<r^3|a_{N+1}|\\\\
&\vdots\\\\
&\left|\frac{a_{N+m}}{a_{N+m-1}}\right|<r\implies |a_{N+m}|<r^{m-1}|a_{N+1}|
\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes I see the pattern but why does the $r$ go up in power? And again, why is $n$ being replaced with $N$?

Comment: @Mark Mark (my name too by the way), for the question on power, $if z=2y$ and $y=2x$, then $z=4x$.  And if $z<2y$ and $y<2x$, then $z<4x$.  Do those conclusions make sense?  If so, then have another look at the logical flow in this answer.  There $|a_{N+m}|<r|a_{N+m-1}$ and $|a_{N+m-1}|<r|a_{N+m-2}$ imply that $|a_{N+m}|<r^2|a_{N+m-2}$.  Proceeding inductively, $|a_{N+m}|<r^{m-1}|a_{N+1}$.

Comment: @Mark Mark, on the question regarding $n$ and $N$, $N$ does not replace $n$.  It is a starting point for the aforementioned recurrence $|a_{N+2}|<r|a_{N+1}|$.  Then, we build to $|a_{N+m}|<r^{m-1}|a_{N+1}$ for all $m$.  Now, $m$ is the running index in a series - like $n$ - and we have $$\left|\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{N+m}\right| \le |a_{N+1}|\, \sum_{m=1}^\infty r^{m-1}=\frac{|a_{N+1}|}{1-r}<\infty$$and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: Sorry. I have been absorbing all the information in. Let me think about it some more and I will definitely reply on here again for sure. I promise. I just want to make sure that I am not just missing an obvious point that I am making complicated.

Comment: Okay I think I understand the argument for $r$ now, so I am good there. As far as $N$ goes. I understand now that $N$ is the starting point. And since $N$ is a natural number, I assume that is why we go up by $1$ each time ($N+1,N+2$, etc). So does this particular series test deal with sequences which is why we incorporate the $N$ in this proof?